# d3 exit function not removing 1st element of group

Tags: d3.js, exit

I'm currently learning d3.js and having an issue when trying to remove all circles I have created. I have been through the forum posts and identified that you should have a function in data that enables to match both the enter and exit, however I don't seem to make it work properly.

Basically all my circles are removed except one, and it appears to be the first from my selection. I have created a Gist available at [blocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/kaltera/1fd4d6f8e919d753e225). In case you want to recreate it step by step I have put some breakpoints so you just need to launch the developer tools and see what's happening before and after the exit function.

The code abstract can be found below :

Enter function:

```
d3.select("svg")
.selectAll("circle.FranceS2012")
.data(FranceS2012)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class","FranceS2012")
.attr("cx", function(d){
  return x_scale(d.values["MonthYear"]);})
.attr("cy", function(d){return y_scale(d.values["Mean_Odds"]);})
.attr("r",function(d){ return d.values["Count"] / 20;})
.style("fill","#1b9e77");
```

Exit function:

```
d3.select("svg")
.selectAll("circle.FranceS2012")
.data(FranceS2012, function(d){
  return d;})
.exit().remove();
```

It's probably a beginner issue but I really can't get around solving it

Thank you so much for your help and time

Comment: In your `exit`, you rebind the same data but change the [key function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data).  What are you trying to do here?  Usually the key function is some unique property from your data, in your case - `.data(FranceS2012, function(d){ return d.key; })`  If you want to remove them all, set no data:  `d3.select("svg")
.selectAll("circle.FranceS2012").data([]).exit().remove();`

Comment: Thank you Mark for your reply as it solved the issue. The problem comes from my misunderstanding on the enter/exit concept and lack of experience. I tried the return d.key function in data for both the enter and the exit, but it turned out that it wasn't removing any of the circles on the exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might just misunderstand the question, but basically, you want to get rid of all the circles, no matter what?

Because if you use the select().data().exit().remove() pattern, you are removing elements in function of your data. To break it down, you should always keep 2 things in mind when working with data and D3: how many elements does my data contain and secondly, how many elements do I have in the DOM representing that data? Based on that, the result of using the enter() and exit() function will become more clear.

If you data array contains 5 elements and you want to represent them with circles and your DOM does not contain any circles, you are going to use the enter() function, which will append 5 circles, because you pass 5 items as your data.

What you are doing here is probably the reverse. Suppose you have 5 circles in your DOM, but your data changed and you suddenly only have 1 element left in your data array. If you use the .exit() function, D3 will remove 4 circles (5 - 1) from your DOM. There is more to in then that, but I suggest reading up more about the enter() and exit() function. I suspect that your data has changed and that you only have one element left, but I am not sure.

And I think you want to get rid of all the circles, and your data is irrelevant? If that is the case, you can just do the following:

```
d3.selectAll("circle.FranceS2012").remove();
```

That will remove all circles with class FranceS2012, no matter what.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed feedback and useful advice, it's actually quite strange as the data stays the same but only one element remains in the DOM after the exit function. It probably has something to do with the unique key function but I can't figure out why it's behaving like this. Indeed I want to create an animation that would first remove the elements and then bring in some new ones depending on the user's choice, hence removing all circles pertaining to a specific class.

Answer (score -1):

The expedient answer in your case is to simplify the removal of your data:

```
d3.selectAll("circle.FranceS2012").remove();
```

I've forked your repo and link to the raw blocks.org view here: http://bl.ocks.org/peterbsmith2/raw/00f64ff11dd07277ef25/[enter link description here](http://bl.ocks.org/peterbsmith2/raw/00f64ff11dd07277ef25/)

Comment: Thank you for your help Peter, it worked indeed :) I believe I need to revisit the enter/exit function as it's still blurry to me ! See above for detailed comment on what I'm trying to achieve and how I ended up there !